# Why is my pip install not installing netifaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip, python-netifaces

I am working with python 3.8.6 but for some reason it cant build a wheel for netifaces

error:

### C:\Users\cuerv>pip install --upgrade netifaces
Collecting netifaces
Using cached netifaces-0.10.9.tar.gz (28 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\cuerv\downloads\my code\imports\python 3.8.6\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qxm_uil5'
cwd: C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17
Complete output (5 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
Running setup.py clean for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
Installing collected packages: netifaces
Running setup.py install for netifaces ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\cuerv\downloads\my code\imports\python 3.8.6\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b4lmtpzg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\cuerv\downloads\my code\imports\python 3.8.6\Include\netifaces'
cwd: C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17
Complete output (5 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\cuerv\downloads\my code\imports\python 3.8.6\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-femvpx3w\netifaces_673ef3fc78424548962ff6e3f9ac8b17\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b4lmtpzg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\cuerv\downloads\my code\imports\python 3.8.6\Include\netifaces' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 2):

The relevant line is this:

```
Complete output (5 lines): 
running install running build running build_ext building 'netifaces' extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. 
Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

It is telling you that to complete the install you need to go get the tools it mentions and install them.   The package is trying to run a compile during install and it needs those tools

Comment: Is there any way to avoid running a compile while installing ? It many cases it is absolutely not appropriate to run a compile (ie: install a compiler, system dependencies and so on) when installing a packages. I used to rely on pip --prefer-binary for that, but for some reason that doesn't work any more with netifaces.

Comment: There is a precompiled version of netifaces available.  check here:  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  for the package.   you should be able to install it directly from the downloaded package.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually I could even do that myself (compile binary package on another machine, copy it on the target machine and install it). But I still believe pip should do the job and the precompiled versions should be available on pypi. Compiling a package may be right for a developer but looks unfit for deploiement.

Comment: I don't disagree,   I prefer packages (when possible) that only have python content and do not need to ship what would be an opaque binary.

Comment: Hi guys, landed this error when trying to install packages with pip. So far I've able to download the .whl file, but do not know how to move on from here. Would love your assistance with resolving this. Thanks

Comment: Figured it out

-> pip install C:\Patht\to\.whl